# How to clear the object store in Mulesoft standalone cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, mule4

Is there any way to clear the object store (default file persistent store) in Mulesoft standalone (4.3.0) cluster.

Below is the retrieve configuration -

```
<os:retrieve doc:name="Retrieve lastSuccessRunTime" doc:id="xxxx" key="lastSuccessRunTime" target="lastRunDate">
            <os:default-value ><![CDATA[#["first run"]]]></os:default-value>
        </os:retrieve>
```

The object store can be cleared by deleting the objectstore folder (.mule//objectstore), then deploying again on local machine or single node standalone.
However, this approach doesn't work for cluster mode - the app can still retrieve the value saved before in the store in cluster (no idea how is the value retrieved).

I want to reset the objectstore so the default value is returned to retrieve all historical data in following process, but now stuck with how to clear the store in cluster.

Will restart the cluster servers help (one server at a time so no outage is introduced)? haven't tried this because wondering if it is the correct direction, and there are many apps in the server which may take long time to completely reboot with apps back.

The last way I can think is to create a backdoor API that executes the clear operation of the store..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last method you mentioned -execute the clear operation- is the only one you should ever be using to clear an object store. Never delete files in .mule, unless you are absolutely sure they are corrupt and unrecoverable. That applies to any files in .mule. How do you invoke is up to you.

If you are talking about a development environment it may be ok to clean the environment, but don't try to do it in production to avoid losing data.

I think you are wrong with the cluster. The default object store configuration for Mule clusters is distributed memory. That means that the data is sincronized between nodes and it is not written to disk. That mean that if you reboot one node as a time the others will preserve the object store values, as the cluster is designed to do. You would need to shutdown all nodes at the same time to make it forget the object store.

Comment: you are right, was trying to find out a way to manually reset the object store even it is saved in memory. The cleanest way is to execute the clear operation of object store.